# What is kinetic arrest?

Tags: phase-transition, kinetic-theory

I know what kinetic energy is and what chemical kinetics is, but what is kinetic arrest? Could someone please explain?

There is no Wikipedia article, and googling throws up only journal articles (about phase transitions). So looking for some enlightenment here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kinetic arrest is complicated, you find it in the production of glass see "Formation from a supercooled liquid" in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass
also there is only the description of the process not the wording kinetic arrest

Comment: Do you have any better references? The wikipedia paragraph isn't very clear for a beginner.